# Garbage collecting objects in Django

Tags: python, django, garbage-collection, django-queryset, django-signals

I have a *one-to-many* relationship, and I would like to automatically delete the *one* side after the last referencing object on the *many* side has been deleted. That is to say, I want to perform garbage collection, or do a kind of reverse cascade operation.

I have tried to solve this by using Django's post_delete signal. Here is a simplified example of what I'm trying to do:

#### models.py

```py
class Bar(models.Model):
    j = models.IntegerField()
    # implicit foo_set

class Foo(models.Model):
    i = models.IntegerField()
    bar = models.ForeignKey(Bar)

def garbage_collect(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    # Bar should be deleted after the last Foo.
    if instance.bar.foo_set.count() == 0:
        instance.bar.delete()

post_delete.connect(garbage_collect, Foo)
```

This works when using `Model.delete`, but with `QuerySet.delete` it breaks horribly.

#### tests.py

```py
class TestGarbageCollect(TestCase):
    # Bar(j=1)
    # Foo(bar=bar, i=1)
    # Foo(bar=bar, i=2)
    # Foo(bar=bar, i=3)
    fixtures = ['db.json']

    def test_separate_post_delete(self):
        for foo in Foo.objects.all():
            foo.delete()
        self.assertEqual(Foo.objects.count(), 0)
        self.assertEqual(Bar.objects.count(), 0)
```

This works just fine.

#### tests.py continued

```py
    def test_queryset_post_delete(self):
        Foo.objects.all().delete()
        self.assertEqual(Foo.objects.count(), 0)
        self.assertEqual(Bar.objects.count(), 0)
```

This breaks on the second time the signal is emitted, because as [Django's documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.delete) says, `QuerySet.delete` is applied instantly, and `instance.bar.foo_set.count() == 0` is true already on the first time the signal is emitted. Still reading from the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.delete), `QuerySet.delete` will emit `post_delete` signal for every deleted object, and `garbage_collect` gets called after `Bar` has been deleted.

To the questions then:

1. Is there a better way of garbage collecting the *one* side of a *one-to-many* relationship?
2. If not, what should I change to be able to use QuerySet.delete?

Answer (score 2):

By checking code in `delete()` inside `django/db/models/deletion.py`, I found the `QuerySet.delete` deletes collected instances in batch and ***THEN*** trigger `post_delete` for those deleted instances. If you delete `Bar()` in the first `post_delete` calling for the first deleted `Foo()` instance, later `post_delete` of  `Foo()` instances will be failed because the `Bar()` which they point to has already been deleted.

The key here is that `Foo()`s having same bar does not point to the same `Bar()` instance, and the bar gets deleted too early. Then we could

- straightly `try...except` the lookup of `instance.bar`

  ```
  def garbage_collect(sender, instance, **kwargs):
      try:
          if instance.bar.foo_set.exists():
              instance.bar.delete()
      except Bar.DoesNotExist:
          pass
  ```
- preload `Bar()` for each instances to avoid the above exception

  ```
  def test_queryset_post_delete(self):
      Foo.objects.select_related('bar').delete()        

  def garbage_collect(sender, instance, **kwargs):
      if instance.bar.foo_set.exists():
          instance.bar.delete()
  ```

Both of above solutions do extra `SELECT` queries. The more graceful ways could be

- Do the deletion of `Bar` always in `garbage_collect` or manually later, if you can:

  ```
  Bar.objects.filter(foo__isnull=True).delete()
  ```
- In `garbage_collect`, record the deletion plan for `Bar()` instead of deleting, to some ref-count flag or queued tasks.

Answer (score 0):

I ques you can override the model's method delete, find the related objects and delete them too.

Comment: I guess I should've included this to the question. `Model.delete` is not called when using `QuerySet.delete`

Comment: Yes, because this method deletes objects in batch without actually fetching them from DB. You can try to write your own manager implementation, which would override in-batch deletion method of queryset to send signal if you acctually need this.

Comment: Please read to question and earlier comments properly before commenting. `QuerySet.delete` emits `pre/post_delete` signals. It does not, however, call `Model.delete`. These are two completely separate things, and I do not wish to break the benefits of `QuerySet.delete` by making it delete one object at a time.